# Creating a link to external route in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce, global

In Woocommerce I am trying to create an external link for pdf generation.

I'm processing the payment in `process_payment` and I'm passing the json result to the `thankyou_page` function, but for some reason the json return when passed to the `thankyou_page` function gets null.

Follow the source code:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$linkBoleto = $response['pdfBoleto'];

function thankyou_page($order_id){
    echo "<a href='".$linkBoleto."' target='_blank'>Boleto</a>";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `thankyou_page` **the variable `$linkBoleto` need to be defined**:

1) You can include it **as an argument** in the function, like:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$linkBoleto = $response['pdfBoleto'];

function thankyou_page($order_id, $linkBoleto){
    echo "<a href='".$linkBoleto."' target='_blank'>Boleto</a>";
}
```

2) You can include it in the function also using `global` like:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$linkBoleto = $response['pdfBoleto'];

function thankyou_page($order_id){
    global $linkBoleto;

    echo "<a href='".$linkBoleto."' target='_blank'>Boleto</a>";
}
```

Now it should work.